# Injected EJB sometimes Null

Tags: ejb-3.0, ejb

I'm using a stateless EJB via the @EJB annotation... most of the time everything works as it should but it seems that from time to time what is supposed to be injected resolves to a NULL causing a null pointer exception.

What could cause this intermittent problem?

Comment: Is it a regular Stateless Bean?

Comment: Yes it is.  I should have mentioned.

Comment: Ok then it shouldn't happen. Does this occur under some particular load or just random? Also, what container are you using?

Comment: I'm using Glassfish... and it was suspected that low memory might be associated... but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 4.x won't automatically inject EJB's into Servlets/JSPs/POJOs.  But it won't complain about the annotations either, it simply won't work at runtime, and the objects will remain Null.  You have to use JNDI lookup.

From the JBoss docs:

> Lookup of EJBs @EJB annotations are
>   usable in servlets and JSPs, but
>   unfortunately, we have not yet updated
>   tomcat to support it. Also, Tomcat
>   works with the old XML format so you
>   cannot use XML either. So for now, you
>   must lookup the EJB via its global
>   JNDI name. This is not compliant, but
>   if you abstract out enough you'll be
>   fine.

**Example:**

```
public void init() throws ServletException
   {
      super.init();
      try
      {
         InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

         // J2EE 1.5 has not yet defined exact XML <ejb-ref> syntax for EJB3
         CalculatorLocal calculator = (CalculatorLocal)ctx.lookup("tutorial/CalculatorBean/local");
         setCalculator(calculator);
      }
      catch (NamingException e)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
}
```

Be sure to use the name of your EAR as the first segment in the name you are looking up (`tutorial` in the example above).

**References:**

- [How do I look up an ejb in jBoss
  4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225148/how-do-i-look-up-an-ejb-in-jboss-4-2)
- [JBoss docs](http://www.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/ear/ear.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but we had the same problem. The most important information is that, this happens sometimes and we could not find out why.

Second thing that whe had noticed was that there was problem with fields that were in "parent" class f.e. we have a class

```java
public abstract class SessionContained {
    @EJB
    protected SessionStoreLocal sessionStoreEJB;

    ....
}
```

```java
@Stateless
public class SomeEJB extends SessionContained {

    @EJB
    SomeAnotherRemote anotherEJB;

    ...
}
```

In debug `SomeAnotherRemote anotherEJB;` was correctly initialized but `SessionStoreLocal sessionStoreEJB;` was null.

We found some work around for this problem, first create EjbUtil class:

```java
public class EjbUtil
{
    public static String ejbContextClassName = System.getProperty("ejbContextClass", EJB31Context.class.getName());
    public static EjbContext ejbContext;

    public static <T> T lookup(Class<T> interfejz)
    {
        Log log = new Log(EjbUtil.class);
        try {
            log.trace("EJButil.lookup: {}", interfejz.getName());

            return getEJBContext().lookup(interfejz);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Blad podczas operacji lookup", e.getCause());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static EjbContext getEJBContext()
            throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        if (ejbContext == null) {
            try {
                Class<EjbContext> clazz = (Class<EjbContext>)Class.forName(ejbContextClassName);
                ejbContext = clazz.getConstructor(new Class[] {}).newInstance((Object[])null);
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {
                Log log = new Log(EjbUtil.class);
                log.error("Blad podczas inicjalizacji ejbContext", e.getCause());
            }
        }
        return ejbContext;
    }
}
```

and add:

```java
public abstract class SessionContained {

    @EJB
    private SessionStoreLocal sessionStoreEJB;

    @NotLogged
    public SessionStoreLocal getSessionStoreLocal() {
        if (sessionStoreEJB == null) {
            log.warn("SessionStoreLocal is null! Trying to retrieve instance.");
            sessionStoreEJB = EjbUtil.lookup(SessionStoreLocal.class);
            if (sessionStoreEJB == null) {
                log.error("SessionStoreLocal is null! Returning null as homenet session.");
                return null;
            }

        }
        return sessionStoreEJB;
}
```

It looks like it works for now.... Maybe it will help someone dealing with this old code.